# amCharts 5 - How to customize legend text color

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts5

Good morning,

I'm trying to figure out how to change the base color of a chart's legend.

**am5 default behaviour** is: the label appears **dark gray**; when clicking on it (the corresponding data is hidden and) the label goes **light gray**.

**The desired behaviour** is: the label appears of **{stroke} color**; when clicking on it (the corresponding data is hidden and) the label goes **light gray**.

I tried using formatting in legendLabelText, like

`legendLabelText: "[{stroke}]{name}[/]"`

Unfortunately this is **not the solution** because the label initially appears of the **{stroke} color**, but when clicking on it (the corresponding data is hidden so) I expect it to go light gray, but it stays of the **{stroke} color**.

Here a basic fiddle showing the case: https://jsfiddle.net/fhryacsL/

Thank you everybody in advance!

Comment: This was answered in GitHub issue: https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts5/issues/1285#issuecomment-1893166828